# MySQL stored procedure and PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a function in a PHP class where I'm trying to create and run a stored procedure but I can't seem to get the variables to pass to the stored procedure. If I manually type the `dateStart`, `dateEnd`, and `user_id` then things run as expected, but not when I'm trying to bind variables to it (I even tried using straight up PHP variables to no avail):

```
 try {
      $sql = $conn->prepare("
           DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS datespopulate;
           DELIMITER |
           CREATE PROCEDURE datespopulate(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE, user_id)
           BEGIN
                WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
                     INSERT INTO timesheet (DATE_YYYYMMDD, USER_ID) VALUES (dateStart, user_id);
                     SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
                END WHILE;
           END;
           |
           DELIMITER ;
           CALL datespopulate(:startdate,:enddate,:user_id);
           ");
      $sql->execute(array(
           ':startdate'=> $startdate,
           ':enddate'=> $enddate,
           ':user_id'=> $userid));
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(); }
```

I tried `bindparam` instead but that didn't seem to work either (maybe I was doing it wrong?). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved this by editing my original code. I failed in two things. For one, I didn't specify what kind of variable user_id was when creating the procedure (should have typed `user_id INT`). Second, I had to separate ALL variables to insert them using prepared statement. An array didn't work for me, but if I bound each variable separately then it worked:

```
 $sql = $conn->prepare("CALL datespopulate(:startdate,:enddate,:userid);");
 $sql->bindParam(':startdate', $startdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sql->bindParam(':enddate', $enddate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sql->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sql->execute();
```

Comment: Really, someone down voted this answer? Would love an explanation as to why this deserves a down vote.

Answer (score -2):

As this question is a sure offtopic if answer directly, here are some hints for you how to debug it.

1. create your procedure.
2. make a test call from the console
3. create a test script that contains not a bit from your "entire project's code" but reproduceable testing code only.
4. make a test call with raw values from PHP
5. in the very same test script add PDO with prepared statements call with error reporting enabled.
6. Post both the exact code and it's exact output here.

This way you will make your question at least answerable by strangers.